# Launching multiple virtualbox VM's from one windows shortcut (.bat?)

Tags: windows, batch-file, virtualbox

Right now I'm launching a single VM using the following windows shortcut:

"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" startvm prima7-clone --type headless

Which launches the VM "prima7-clone" as headless. This works all fine and dandy. Although I'd like to launch an additional VM at the same time. Is it possible to launch multiple targets in a windows shortcut? I was reading that I might be able to do this using a batch file... but my experience with .bat is lacking. Anybody have any solutions?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a batch file:

```
cd MYDIR
start "C:\Progra~1\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" startvm VM1 --type headless
start "C:\Progra~1\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" startvm VM2 --type headless
```

Save these contents in a file something.bat.

Note1: You may need to change MYDIR to whatever directory you want, (typically, the `start in` directory of that shortcut.)
Note2: Change the name of VMs as required.